# Google Sheets setting value of multiple cells in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change the values of a range of code in my spreadsheet, to reset a template back to default values when done. I found this code as an example on another thread, but can't ask there because you can't ask questions or something.

```
function storeValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var values = [
  ["2.000", "1,000,000", "$2.99"]
];

var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D2");
range.setValues(values);

}
```

This works great, changes those three cells to the value needed. This isn't what I ultimately need, but it works. I want to change the values in A8-A10 though, and when I change that cell range(And nothing else),I get the following error:
**Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 3**

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure it's simple.

Comment: Research a bit more about 2d arrays., And then ask yourself what the values array would look like to set values for a range with more than one row and more than one column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values array you have will write to columns in a row. To write to row in a column change to:

```
var values = [["2.000"], ["1,000,000"], ["$2.99"]];
```